# C AVR Serial: Strange behaviour while using integers of different sizes

Tags: c, serial-port, avr

I am trying to get the remainder when two integers are divided.And also trying to get the quotient.My variables are follows:

```
    const uint16_t key = 1000;
    uint8_t remainder;
    uint16_t temp;
     temp = somefunction();  //This returns a uint32_t

     while((UCSR0A&(1<<RXC0)) == 0);  //WAIT FOR CHAR
     //Wait for a char from serial
     remainder = temp % key;
     quotient = (temp/key);

      //Now I check to see if I got the correct remainder
      while((UCSR0A&(1<<UDRE0)) == 0); //wait until empty 
      UDR0 = remainder;
      //The remainder I get in minicom is something I am not expecting.
      //I checked the result of somefunction() and it is correct
```

Please help!

Comment: **What** strange behaviour?

Comment: The remainder is only 8 bit. the values will be less than 256. It looks like you are expecting values up to 999.

Comment: @UncleO,This is actually a part of an encryption code. I did not want to give the details so as to not confuse people.What the somefunction() does it that it reverses the bits of a ASCII char and then makes it an exact 8number long decimial number with only 1 and 0. For example: 84 is 01010100(base2)-->reverse so: 00101010(base2)..Now it is converted to decimal so it becomes: 101010(base10)..I divide this by 1000 which means that the remainder is always 3digits and less than 1000, and always with 1s and 0s.So max remainder can be is 111,which a uint8_t should be able to store.

Comment: @UncleO I think that the problem is in the modulo and division of ints of different sizes as I have checked the result by subtracting the result I get with what I expect and add 48. If the result is right I would get 0 in minicom. I do get a zero, so that function should be giving the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments:

The value which is being returned from `somefunction()` - 101010 - is beyond the range of the `uint16_t` variable `temp` which you are assigning it to. It is being truncated to 35474 (101010 mod 65536) when it is assigned to that variable, which would cause the results of the division and modulo to be 35 and 474, respectively.

You will need to change the type of `temp` to `uint32_t`, and change the type of `remainder` to `uint32_t` as well to avoid truncating the result.

Comment: Thanks..Will try and will let you know!

Answer (score 0):

The value you write to `UDR0` is being sent over serial as a character code, not as a human-readable number. If you want something you can read, you will need to do formatting yourself, or link the C library and use something like `printf()` or `itoa()`.

Comment: I am in fact checking the character with it's decimal value from a ascii table. For cases in which I was expecting remainders to be unreadable I added 48 to them just to check what I got. The answer is still not right.

Comment: Please refer to my comments to UncleO

Comment: In that case, I'm at a loss. You'll need to give a specific example of what behavior you're expecting, and what you're seeing.

Comment: I am expecting to get a remainder of 10(unit8_t) and quotient of 101,when uint32_t value of 101010 is divided by unin16_t value of 1000.